# Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBitwiseAnd' to type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBooleanExpression'

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following code segment in which I'm getting error

```
using (var session = Database.OpenSession())
{
    var q = from x in session.Query<User>()
           where x.UserName == username & x.Password==EncodePassword(password)
            select x;
    if (q.Count() > 0)
     {
         result = true;
     }
}
```

on the if statement I'm getting error

```
Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBitwiseAnd' to type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBooleanExpression'.
```

Comment: The 'BitWiseAnd' is a really big hint here :-)

Comment: @diggingforfire I thought the same thing... Sometimes a good reading makes the difference!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about:

```
using (var session = Database.OpenSession())
{
    var q = from x in session.Query<User>()
           where x.UserName == username && x.Password==EncodePassword(password)
            select x;
    if (q.Count() > 0)
     {
         result = true;
     }
}
```

Check the double ampersand in your query, right in the `where` part.